# Receiving "ActionView::Missing Template" error when hosting locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

Trying to view a Rails app, but when I host it locally I get the following error message:

```
Missing template website_builder_engine/home/index, website_builder_engine/application/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "/Users/MyName/orange-peacock/app/views" * "/Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@mygemset/gems/frontend-helpers-0.1.3/app/views" * "/Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@mygemset/gems/website_builder_engine-0.0.5/app/views" * "/Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@mygemset/gems/devise-2.2.8/app/views"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `index.html.erb` file in `website_builder_engine/home` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that you need to have a view at `/app/views/home/index.html.erb` or `website_builder_engine/home/index.html.erb`

--

I don't think this issue is with `devise` itself, rather how you're accessing the routes in your app. I would imagine that you're redirecting to a route (on unauthentication) which doesn't exist (I.E `home#index`):

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "home#index"
devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: "login" } #-> routes to views/devise/login
```

The way to fix this is to make sure your have the view available, and also to ensure `devise` will redirect to the correct route on authentication

--

A big help would be if you posted your `routes` file

Comment: Thanks for your response. My app/config/routes.rb is as follows:

Rails3MongoidDevise::Application.routes.draw do
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#index'
      mount WebsiteBuilderEngine::Engine, :at => '/builder'

  end
  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
end